# The simple way to sort based on values in a hash in perl

Tags: perl

Normally sorting based on keys and then iterating a hash can be done as following:

```
for $k (sort (keys %h)) {
  print $k, $h{$k};
}
```

But how to do the sorting based on values and then iterate through the hash? I can think of creating a new hash by swapping the key and value pairs. But is there any more clever way of doing this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: perldoc -q sort: How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the sort comparator to be something other than `cmp`, you can supply a code block or a subroutine as the first parameter to `sort`. See [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for more details.

```
my %h = (
    aaaa => 'z',
    bbb  => 'x',
    c    => 'y',
);

# Sort on hash values.
for my $k (sort {$h{$a} cmp $h{$b}} keys %h) {
    print $k, "\n";   # bbb c aaaa
}

# Sort using a named subroutine.
for my $k (sort by_length keys %h) {
    print $k, "\n";   # c bbb aaaa
}

sub by_length {
    length($a) <=> length($b);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This sorts the **%age** hash by **value** instead of **key**

```
@eldest = sort { $age{$b} <=> $age{$a} } keys %age;
```

This does sorting based on value.
For more details refer to Perl Doc:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Comment: How do keep the hash rather than end up with an array?

Answer (score 2):

[How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-%28optionally-by-value-instead-of-key%29?)

If you're going to program in Perl then you should really take the time to read the [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html).