# How do I sort a hash array by value in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a program that finds all the files in a directory and creates a hash array of their names and sizes.

example

```
%files = ("file1" => 10, "file2" => 30, "file3" => 5);
```

I want to be able to sort the files by size descending and add the names/values to a new array.

example

```
%filesSorted = ("file2" => 30, "file1" => 10, "file3" => 5);
```

I have found many ways to sort the array by value and then print the values but that's not what I want.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Hashes are inherently unsorted. Your `%files` and `%filesSorted` are equivalent; you'd get the same effect by just writing `%filesSorted = %files;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The simple way to sort based on values in a hash in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972224/the-simple-way-to-sort-based-on-values-in-a-hash-in-perl)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use the search (or google) before posting new questions; many have already been asked and answered.

Comment: Pardon a silly question, but for what reason would you sort a hash? If you access a single value, like `$files{"file1"}` it doesn't matter if its sorted, and if you want to loop, you have to have the keys, and then its much easier to just sort the keys `for ( sort { $files{$a} <=> $files{$b} } keys %files ) { ... }`.

Comment: This is in the Perl FAQ.

Answer (score 8):

You must put the names of the files into an *array* in sorted order. Unlike Perl hashes, arrays are ordered and will retain their order. This code demonstrates the point using your own data

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %files = (file1 => 10, file2 => 30, file3 => 5);

my @sorted = sort { $files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } keys %files;

foreach my $file (@sorted) {
  print "$file => $files{$file}\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
file2 => 30
file1 => 10
file3 => 5
```

Comment: Borodin - Correct the output and code.It should be descending. It should be `sort {$files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } keys %files;`

Comment: That code can also be a little neater using `List::UtilsBy::revsort_by`:
    use List::UtilsBy qw( revsort_by );
    my @sorted = revsort_by { $files{$_} } keys %files;