# How can I sort a hash with objects in perl

Tags: perl

I need to sort (or re-arrange keys) a hash with objects by looking on a common  attribute(eg: `val1`) on those objects. How can I do that?

[image: Sample]

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: See also http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)%3f - this is a FAQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The simple way to sort based on values in a hash in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972224/the-simple-way-to-sort-based-on-values-in-a-hash-in-perl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to use an array-based object for illustration.

```
package obj;

sub new { my $class = shift; bless [@_], $class }
sub val1 { my $self = shift; $self->[0] }
sub val2 { my $self = shift; $self->[1] }
sub val3 { my $self = shift; $self->[2] }

package main;

my %hash = (
    p => obj->new(4,2,5),
    e => obj->new(1,2,5),
    z => obj->new(2,2,5),
    x => obj->new(3,2,5),
);

# sort the keys of hash according to the 'val1' attribute
my @keys = sort { $hash{$a}->val1 <=> $hash{$b}->val1 } keys %hash;

print join(", ", @keys);
```

Will print `e, z, x, p`.

Note that if the object uses hash-based representation, as is the case with your example code, you can either use the above code or simply access the attribute directly as hash.

```
# sort the keys of hash according to the 'val1' attribute
my @keys = sort { $hash{$a}{val1} <=> $hash{$b}{val1} } keys %hash;
```

Comment: Also check out [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) for sorting by possibly slow method calls more efficiently: `use List::UtilsBy 'nsort_by'; my @keys = nsort_by { $hash{$_}->val1 } keys %hash;`